# Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Web resource X.js was not found

Tags: javascript, web, resources, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

We are bundling JavaScript files using ScriptResource.axd. On my local machine its working fine. But after deployment I am getting error

> EXCEPTION: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Web resource '/(a(myasmwidtz24pjpixc3mqfdf7ta4etz9aelxf_4vxqet7u1))/js/xyz.js was not found..

When I checked file is present at the expected path. I don't know what is happening behind the scene. As you can see after slash " (a" is coming what does this imply?

Comment: Do readers need to see your configuration for this? There is not a lot of detail to go on here.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: In Website root folder we have below folder structure :
JS folder which contains xyz.js
JS folder have another folder called Y which contains abc.js